# Springboot with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot

When i added springboot plugi to my Selenium application. Selenium stoped work.

Here is my minimal example code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/rafal/geckodriver");
        WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        webDriver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

and gradle:

```
group 'testSeleniumasdf'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.4.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

And it works...

But when i add springboot to my gradle, like here :

```
group 'testSeleniumasdf'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.4.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

It doesn't work. It was 45s timeout. And log :

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
amed-provider>
1500922321841   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1500922321841   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1500922321902   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1500922321902   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
1500922321902   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1500922321919   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1500922321919   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1500922321921   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_0_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.0.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/rafal/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.0] using wine prefix directory /home/rafal/.wine-pipelight.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.0] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[install-dependency] wine-silverlight5.0-installer is already installed in '/home/rafal/.wine-pipelight'.
[install-dependency] wine-mpg2splt-installer is already installed in '/home/rafal/.wine-pipelight'.
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.9.7 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
wine: Nie znaleziono biblioteki DLL.
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (1157)
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] embedded mode         is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] windowless mode       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] linux windowless mode is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] force SetWindow       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] window class hook     is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] strict draw ordering  is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function CreateWindowExA.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function CreateWindowExW.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function TrackPopupMenuEx.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function TrackPopupMenu.
fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW (0x7b8d1f07, 0x7b96f118, {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x68f628, (null), (null), 0x7b96f118): stub
fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] init successful!
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] OpenGL Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] Your GPU is in the whitelist, hardware acceleration should work.
1500922322191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322192   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322196   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1500922322196   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1500922322209   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1500922322210   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
amed-provider>
1500922321841   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1500922321841   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1500922321902   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1500922321902   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
1500922321902   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1500922321919   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1500922321919   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1500922321921   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_0_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.0.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/rafal/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.0] using wine prefix directory /home/rafal/.wine-pipelight.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.0] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[install-dependency] wine-silverlight5.0-installer is already installed in '/home/rafal/.wine-pipelight'.
[install-dependency] wine-mpg2splt-installer is already installed in '/home/rafal/.wine-pipelight'.
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.9.7 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
wine: Nie znaleziono biblioteki DLL.
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (1157)
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] embedded mode         is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] windowless mode       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] linux windowless mode is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] force SetWindow       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] window class hook     is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] strict draw ordering  is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function CreateWindowExA.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function CreateWindowExW.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function TrackPopupMenuEx.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function TrackPopupMenu.
fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW (0x7b8d1f07, 0x7b96f118, {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x68f628, (null), (null), 0x7b96f118): stub
fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] init successful!
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] OpenGL Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] Your GPU is in the whitelist, hardware acceleration should work.
1500922322191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322192   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322196   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1500922322196   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1500922322209   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1500922322210   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'rafal-Lenovo-G510', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.2.0-36-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
amed-provider>
1500922321841   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1500922321841   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1500922321902   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1500922321902   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19
1500922321902   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1500922321919   addons.repository   DEBUG   No addons.json found.
1500922321919   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1500922321921   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_0_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.0.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/rafal/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/etc/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.0'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] sandbox not found or not installed!
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.0] using wine prefix directory /home/rafal/.wine-pipelight.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.0] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[install-dependency] wine-silverlight5.0-installer is already installed in '/home/rafal/.wine-pipelight'.
[install-dependency] wine-mpg2splt-installer is already installed in '/home/rafal/.wine-pipelight'.
fixme:winediag:start_process Wine Staging 1.9.7 is a testing version containing experimental patches.
fixme:winediag:start_process Please mention your exact version when filing bug reports on winehq.org.
wine: Nie znaleziono biblioteki DLL.
err:wineboot:ProcessRunKeys Error running cmd L"C:\\windows\\system32\\winemenubuilder.exe -a -r" (1157)
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] embedded mode         is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] windowless mode       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] linux windowless mode is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] force SetWindow       is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] window class hook     is on.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] strict draw ordering  is off.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function CreateWindowExA.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function CreateWindowExW.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function TrackPopupMenuEx.
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] replaced API function TrackPopupMenu.
fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW (0x7b8d1f07, 0x7b96f118, {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}, 1, 0x68f628, (null), (null), 0x7b96f118): stub
fixme:ntdll:EtwRegisterTraceGuidsW   register trace class {aa087e0e-0b35-4e28-8f3a-440c3f51eef1}
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] init successful!
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] OpenGL Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] OpenGL Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
[PIPELIGHT:WIN:silverlight5.0] Your GPU is in the whitelist, hardware acceleration should work.
1500922322191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322191   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322192   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1500922322196   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1500922322196   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1500922322209   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1500922322210   DeferredSave.addons.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:22291): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:113)
    ... 7 more
```

It seems spring boot manage selenium in some other way. Maybe someone know how to run this code example with springboot. Help please.

Comment: Do you have firefox installed and is it available from the command line?

Comment: Yes it is. And as i wrote without spring-boot dependency everything works ok.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what your using springboot for as your code doesn't use it but for what its worth Springboot has a different main class than typical.

Try changing your main like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Main implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void  main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/rafal/geckodriver");
        WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        webDriver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

The SpringApplication.run method will start a tomcat server and do some other [magic](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-main-method) which will make Spring happy, and the [run method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner) takes advantage of the Spring framework to execute logic immediately after Spring has initialized but before the SpringApplication.run method has completed.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I know that I did not properly spring boot application. But I noticed that usage only springboot plugin it's enough to get an error. I used your code example but the same problem appered.

Answer (score 0):

I had to define all of the selenium dependencies explictly, not just selenium-java.  Update your gradle dependencies with these other selenium dependencies.

```
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-leg-rc:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-edge-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-ie-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-opera-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-safari-driver:${seleniumVersion}"
compile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:${seleniumVersion}"
```

Answer (score 0):

please verify that port 7055 is not occupied else the port is not correct.